# How to calculate time duration using Microsoft SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms, datediff

I want to find the time duration for each person from one start time. I want to calculate the time duration from 1 start time for each day and multiple end times for multiple users. This is my code:

```
SELECT *,
      CAST(DATEDIFF(n, CAST(End_Time AS datetime), 
      CAST(Start_Time AS datetime))  AS FLOAT) / 60 AS Time_Duration
FROM 
     ( SELECT  NAME,
               MAX(CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'Green' THEN Final_Value END) AS Start_Time,
               MAX(CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'Red' THEN Final_Value END) AS End_Time
       FROM mydata
       WHERE NAME != ‘NA’
       GROUP BY NAME
     ) C
```

I am not able to get any results for time duration. 
This is what my output looks like:

```
    Name        Start_time           End_time        Time_Duration 
1   Day_1       5/6/15 2:30
2   John                           5/6/15 3:30          
3   Ben                            5/6/15 4:30          
4   Mike                           5/6/15 5:30          
5   Day_2       5/7/15 2:30
6   John_2                         5/7/15 4:30          
7   Ben_2                          5/7/15 5:30          
8   Mike_2                         5/7/15 6:30
```

I want it to look like this:

```
    Name        Start_time           End_time        Time_Duration 
1   Day_1      5/6/15 2:30
2   John                           5/6/15 3:30          1.00
3   Ben                            5/6/15 4:30          2.00
4   Mike                           5/6/15 5:30          3.00
5   Day_2      5/7/15 2:30
6   John_2                         5/7/15 4:30          2.00
7   Ben_2                          5/7/15 5:30          3.00
8   Mike_2                         5/7/15 6:30          4.00
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Looks like sql server/t-sql function. Could you please give more details on your logic? You have either start or end time as NULL in the same row, it's the reason you are not getting the right result

Comment: The problem: Your outer `SELECT` works on one row at a time. Your inner `SELECT` however produces multiple rows that you need to combine. Unfortunately I lack the time to help further now, but maybe my analysis helps...

Comment: The problem is that the start and end times are not in the same row, why are you storing the day name and the user name in the same column?. Also, how do you know that, for example, "John" should use the start time of day 1 and not of day 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the values in name column has suffix of the day number (and none for day 1)

```
WITH td AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [day] ORDER BY final_value) rnum
  FROM (SELECT *,
               CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_', name) = 0
                    THEN '1'
                    ELSE SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX('_', name) + 1, LEN(name) - CHARINDEX('_', name))
                END [day]           
           FROM t_dur
        ) tt
)

SELECT t1.name, 
       CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN t1.final_value END start_time,
       CASE WHEN rnum <> 1 THEN t1.final_value END end_time,
       CASE CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, (SELECT t2.final_value FROM td t2 WHERE t2.[day] = t1.[day] AND t2.rnum = 1),
                       t1.final_value) AS DECIMAl(5,2)) 
            WHEN 0 THEN NULL
            ELSE CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, (SELECT t2.final_value FROM td t2 WHERE t2.[day] = t1.[day] AND t2.rnum = 1),
                       t1.final_value) AS DECIMAl(5,2)) 
         END time_duration
  FROM td t1
```

Result

```
name    start_time              end_time                time_duration
Day_1   2015-05-06 02:30:00.000 NULL                    NULL
John    NULL                    2015-05-06 03:30:00.000 1.00
Ben     NULL                    2015-05-06 04:30:00.000 2.00
Mike    NULL                    2015-05-06 05:30:00.000 3.00
Day_2   2015-05-07 02:30:00.000 NULL                    NULL
John_2  NULL                    2015-05-07 04:30:00.000 2.00
Ben_2   NULL                    2015-05-07 05:30:00.000 3.00
Mike_2  NULL                    2015-05-07 06:30:00.000 4.00
```